# How can they ride for 160 days in Mad Max: Fury Road?

Tags: mad-max, mad-max-fury-road

In the new Mad Max: Fury Road,

> after they hook up with Furiosa's clan, they load up the motorcycles and prepare to abandon the war rig and ride across the salt. Furiosa explains the plan to Max.

She states that they have enough fuel and supplies to ride for 160 days. She says it casually and it is repeated several times, so it's clearly not a mistake.

This is an unbelievably long time to ride without resupplying. Even if the bikes were solar powered and they had stillsuits that captured all but a liter of water, that's still an unmanageable 160 kg of water each.

Is there anything in the film (or other Mad Max material) that could explain how a group on motorcycles could carry enough food, water, and supplies to ride for 160 days?

Comment: Are we going to ignore the fact that riding for 160 days would get you all the way around the world. Twice.

Comment: Could they be using days as a measure of distance, rather than time? If one day of travelling (**walking**) was 10 miles, I could travel for 100 "days" in a single 24 hour period.

Comment: @Richard - then they'd have to ride for 12 parsecs...

Comment: @richard I really like that idea. In the wasteland without good markers, it may make sense to measure distance in 'daywalks'. 5 days away would mean 5 days hiking. Much faster biking.

Comment: Are we sure she's saying 160 days and not something like "another 60 days"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To explicitly answer your question: no.

There is no information 'in-universe' that would explain how the clan and Max could survive so long in the wasteland. The Max universe doesn't spend too much time detailing survival techniques, rather it focuses on action set-pieces ;)
Not that it's not an interesting question.

Comment: There's really only one possibility - they intend to try to live off the land along the way. Max expresses his skepticism to this when he indicates that there is "nothing but salt" out there.